# Losing my saved settings each time I boot up from my usb

Tags: boot

I'm a very new user to Ubuntu and everytime a boot with my usb stick I have to reinstall all the apps that I had previously downloaded. Why is this so??  How do I save everything so that I can just have it there ready for me to use?? Instead of downloading it each time?? I know that this seems like a silly question but I really could use some help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to recreate your boot stick.
I tested this using UNetBootin. If you don't have it installed you will have to install it using Software Center (or by using `sudo apt-get install unetbootin` in terminal).
In the lower part of the window you have to select the amount of space used to preserve settings and files across reboots (default is 0). Set this value to whatever suits you (depending also on the usb stick capacity, of course). Then, if everyting else is set click OK to create the disk.

Comment: I tried putting it in the terminal and but it said that it was unable to locate package unetbootin.

Comment: @user2954906: sorry for the delay. Probably you don't have the "universe" repository selected. Please add it using one of the methods described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and try again.